# Establishing connection w/ Amazon s3 from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, amazon-s3, heroku

I am attempting to deploy my first app on Heroku and having a little trouble getting the S3 connection to work.

Here is the error I am getting from the Heroku logs:

```
AWS::S3::CurrentBucketNotSpecified (No bucket name can be inferred from your current connection's address (`s3.amazonaws.com')):
```

I have the following configured:

**config/s3.yml**

```
development:
    bucket_name: dev.myapp.mycompany
    access_key_id: <####>
    secret_access_key: <####>

test:
    bucket_name: test.myapp.mycompany
    access_key_id: <####>
    secret_access_key: <####>

production:
    bucket_name: production.myapp.mycompany
    access_key_id: <####>
    secret_access_key: <####>
```

**Project Model**

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_attached_file :preview,
        :storage => :s3, 
        :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", 
        :path => "/:style/:filename",
        :styles => {
          :thumb => "72x44",
          :small => "312x192"
        }

        has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy


end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config is :bucket, not :bucket_name

http://docs.heroku.com/s3

Comment: that did it. I was using the code for attachment fu there. Didn't realize that slight diff and doesn't call attention to it in the doc. Thanks.